How can I combine multiple files into a single larger file on a non-virtual filesystem?
Is there any filesystem where I can say map file1, file2, file3 and file4 together to file1234?
file1 is 100M
file2 is 100M
file3 is 100M
file4 is 100M
... and file1234 will then be 400M, and it is safely stored in this filesystem?
not a virtual-filesystem, it must be saved at filesystem.

Do you mean you want to concatenate all four files, and access the data through the concatenated file, but if any of the four files changes, the concatenated data should automatically be kept up to date (as a feature of the filesystem)?

no, the four files will not change. i think the filesystemtable must can a feature to map files together and store them  so and remove the old entries. which filesystem have this features?

You could concatenate the files with the cat command to create the large file (cat file1 file2 file3 file4 >file1234), but this may not be what you mean. You want the filesystem to present the large file somehow without using more space? Do you need to be able to seamlessly search back and forth in the combined data, or read it more than once? This is unusual and not something I've ever seen done in a classical Unix filesystem.  Plan 9 or GNU Hurd may implement something that might do this, but I am unfamiliar with either of these OSes.

I suppose you could let whatever needs to read the combined data read the output of that cat command in my previous comment, from a pipe (instead of writing it to a file).  But that would not allow you to treat the data as a file, nor would you be able to read it more than once without re-running the cat command.  It depends on how you need to access the data, which you say nothing about in your question.

i am unfamiliar with either of these OSes too.
by copy a file into some nested encription layers it goes slow.
but the ssd drive and my cpu has many resources free.
if i do copy parallel at the same time 4 diferent pices (4* 100M) from the one 400M file into, it goes faster. that is the reason why i am looking for a filesystem that can map 4 files to 1. my test-file is a videofile. it is only for reading.

Linux filesystems by and large are not like relational databases.  You can't construct a "view" that spans files the way some database engines will let you create a view that spans tables.
You can create a temporary concatenation of some files, which a running script/command can read from start to end.  However, this only lasts while the script/command is running, it's not saved permanently to disk.  If you have only a few commands that need to read once in a while, then the temp concatenation (process substitution) might be useful to you.
